# Geocoding EXIF tags

Tags: image, geocoding, exif

What are the exif tags for geocoded data in an image called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GPSLatitude` and `GPSLongitude` usually, from what I've seen.  Though there's a [comprehensive reference](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) on the subject with considerably more.

Comment: Google and Canon also use/support Latitude and Longitude both in decimal and degrees. I'm adding this now (even so much farther in the future) because this is coming-up in searches and I want it to be emphasized that the ones I mentioned are the only ones that I tend to see.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to a table of GPS tags. [GPS EXIF tags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html)